# Is there a global handler for async Errors?

Tags: dart

In old-fashioned sync code, you can always assure your program won't crash completely by encapsulation your source code to the one big try catch block as in example:

```
try {
  // Some piece of code
} catch (e) {
  logger.log(e); // log error
}
```

However in Dart, when using `Future`s and `Stream`s, it is not so easy. Following example will crash your application completely

```
try {
  doSomethingAsync().then((result) => throw new Exception());
} catch (e) {
  logger.log(e);
}
```

It doesn't matter that you have code inside the `try`-`catch` block.

Yes, you can always use `Future.catchError`, unfortunately, this won't help you if you are using third-party library function as following:

```
void someThirdPartyDangerousMethod() {
  new Future.value(true).then((result) => throw new Exception());
}

try {
  // we can't use catchError, because this method does not return Future
  someThirdPartyDangerousMethod(); 
} catch (e) {
  logger.log(e);
}
```

Is there a way to prevent the untrusty code to break whole your application? Something like global error handler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the brand new `Zone`s. Just run your code inside the `Zone` and attach error handler to it.

```
void someThirdPartyDangerousMethod() {
  new Future.value(true).then((result) => throw new Exception());
}

runZoned(() {
  // we can't use catchError, because this method does not return Future
  someThirdPartyDangerousMethod(); 
}, onError: (e) {
  logger.log(e);
});
```

This should just work as expected! Every uncatched error will be handled by the `onError` handler. One thing is different to the classical example with `try`-`catch` block. The code running inside the `Zone` won't stop when error occurs, error is handled by `onError` callback and the application continues.